# R - How to build a filename with variables

Tags: r, character, filenames

I know that this is very easy in Phython, but I dont find any solutions in R for my problem:

I want to create multiple files like that:

```
write.table(df, "EUmax_20J_1993.dat", row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE) 
write.table(df, "EUmax_10J_1994.dat", row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE) 
write.table(df, "EUmax_20J_1996.dat", row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE) 
write.table(df, "EUmax_10J_1993.dat", row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE)
```

In the beginning of my script I have this:

```
 Years = 10
 From = 1993
```

I use one script for all these outputs, I only change the amount of years and the startyear at the beginning of the script. Its running for the years I selected and then I want to adjust the output-name automatically. In Python you just combine characters with a simple plus.

In R I dont get it working, I tried this:

```
Years = as.character(Years)
From = as.character(From)
write.table(df, "EUmax_J_"+Years+"_"+From+".dat", row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE)
```

It doesnt work and I dont find anything about how to connect characters like this.

Comment: Yeah, you need something like `paste0("EUmax_J_", Years, "_", From, ".dat")`

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try it!

Comment: Or `?sprintf` ...

Answer (score 2):

If you want filenames like this:

```
write.table(df, "EUmax_10J_1993.dat", row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE)
```

to be created dynamically you use paste:

```
years <- 10
from <- 1993 

file_name <- paste(“EUmax_”, years, “J_”, from, “.dat”, col=“”, sep=“”)
write.table(df, file_name, row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE)
```